# Basic authentication error while using Python-jira using api key

Tags: python-3.x, jira, python-jira

I am trying to do basic authentication with the help of Python-jira and written the following code

```
from jira import JIRA
SERVER="https://jira.company.com"
user = user@company.com
apikey='api_token'

class create_issue:

    def check_authentication(self):
        print("inside the check authentication method@@@@@@@")
        jira = JIRA(options, basic_auth=(user, apikey)) # username is email-ID and apikey is the JIRA api-token

ci= create_issue()
ci.check_authentication()
```

I am getting following error

```
WARNING:root:Got recoverable error from GET https://jira.company.com/rest/api/2/serverInfo, will retry [1/3] in 13.772170596345521s. Err: 401
```

Earlier tried with deprecated username and password, later changed to api_key instead of password. But still getting the issue. Can anybody help on this. When I use the same authentication using the website it is working.

Thanks,
Punith

Answer (score -1):

Their documentation indicates that you should be using a username and password when using basic auth, not an apikey.

https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/basic-authentication/

Stick to something simple to make sure it works, before introducing classes.

```py
from jira import JIRA

SERVER="https://jira.company.com"

user = "username"
password = "password"


jira = JIRA(SERVER, basic_auth=(user, password))
```